# Preventing OSX from using "smart" curly quotes

Tags: macos, encoding, characters, evernote

Is there a way to prevent OSX from using curly double and single quotes by default? I use Evernote to store SQL commands for reference and instead of getting `"` and `'` when typing I end up with `‘` and `”`. It's annoying to say the least.

From what I understand, this has nothing to do with Evernote because it's just using the standard encoding scheme for OSX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply two-finger (right) click the Evernote text area and select `Substitutions` and uncheck `Smart Quotes`. This works for many text areas, but not `<textarea>`s.

[image: "Substitutions" and uncheck "Smart Quotes"]

If you would like to disable it globally, open `System Preferences`, select `Keyboard`, select `Text`, and then uncheck `Use smart quotes and dashes`.

[image]

Comment: I guess it was an Evernote specific thing after all. I wouldn't be opposed to disabling it globally for all apps if possible.

Comment: @ghostfly Volià

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Mac OS issue, rather a font issue.
What font are you using in Evernote? Try using a monotype font like Andale Mono.
I just tested: typed a simple SQL in Evernote, copied-pasted into Sequel Pro, and got results.

Comment: It's much more subtle in Andale Mono, but it's still using the curly versions. I've never used Sequel Pro but maybe that is converting it for you.

Comment: Are you using a language other than U.S.-English?

Comment: Checked up on this - SequelPro *does* automatically convert the smartquotes to normal ones, but other applications won't be as forgiving. @evan.bovie's answer is spot on.